# CSS design templates

Tags: java, css, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I'm about to develop a j2ee web application . I need to know , how can I have the different designs (layout of CSS) for jsp pages . Say If I send the same data always but I want to present that data in different web designs ( web page designs) .

So that I can navigate through the designs more flexibly and choose the best one for my applications.

My need is , with out changing the content related to design in jsp page , (like classname's  , id 's related to CSS for different textboxes and lables.. etc) , instead I'll change only one attribute in my application so that whole design would change.

Can any one suggest where can I find these sets of web layouts  (CSS layouts).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for then is the [960.gs grid system](http://960.gs/).  :)

It provides.. "..a streamlined web development workflow by providing commonly used dimensions..". which is what you have asked for in your question.

Comment: Very confusing one , where can I find good documentation for this

Answer (score 1):

I agree with another poster about having separate CSS Style Sheets (external style sheets).

Have you checked out [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)?  There's probably more than a hundred different web pages that all use the same HTML, but changed the CSS & image files only.  That's what opened my eyes to what CSS can do.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, one way to accomplish changing layout without changing classes and ids is to have separate stylesheets for each layout.

You can then select the desired stylesheet in the header of the html file being served.

i.e

layout 1:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layoutOne.css" />
```

layout 2:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layoutTwo.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reached below link . It sounds great

**http://www.oswd.org**  - You can download from this site many number of designs.
I agree the answer on zengarden , here is the URL http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/alldesigns/